Algorithm of min copies needed to make up a string
I encountered a coding interview question. The problem is like this, you are given a source string and a target string, you can make arbitrary copies of source string and also delete an arbitrary number of chars on the copies, you need to return the minimum number of copies needed in order to make up the target string. If it is not possible then return -1. Note: the copy cannot be inserted in the middle, each copy needs to be concatenated.
Example
if source is "aba" and target is "baba" then return 2, because you can make two copies of source: abaaba, then delete two 'a's to make to baba
another example, source is "aba" and target is "bbccc", then return -1, because no matter how many copies to make, sources cannot make to target.
The solution that I can think of is search + memory. Because we at most need to copy N times where N is the length of the target string. So we can have a for loop of i=1 until N, each iteration we try to see if i copies can make up to target by deleting any char, we try to delete each char one by one to construct a candidate (this is the search problem); the memory would be a cache to record whether we have seen the candidate before and whether this candidate can lead to target, so with the help of the memory our search space is pruned. The algorithm will return immediately on the first i-th iteration when the search process find a possible match. After N iterations, if no early return happens, then return -1 at the end.
Is there any better algorithm than the above?

What's your question?  What's the best algorithm you know so far?  We discourage posts that are just the statement of an exercise- or contest-style task.  You might find this page helpful in improving your question.  Can you credit the source where you encountered this?

https://cs.stackexchange.com/tags/dynamic-programming/info might be helpful

Why do you need to start your search from scratch every time?
